# Why my spark job blocked when do collectasMap

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I read some data from hdfs directly,there is string json in files, but the code is running for 7 hours
[image]

```
val CONSUME_LOW="l"
val CONSUME_HIGH="h"
private val CONSUME_TAG = "consum"
private val CONSUME_LABEL_MAP = Map("low" -> AppPushConfig.CONSUME_LOW, "high" -> AppPushConfig.CONSUME_HIGH)
val consumeTagedCookie = getCookieWithLabel(spark, ZOOKEEPER, CONSUME_TAG)
      .filter(x => CONSUME_ABTEST_CHARSET.contains(x._1.charAt(CONSUME_ABTEST_INDEX).toLower) && CONSUME_LABEL_MAP.contains(x._2))
      .map(x => (x._1, CONSUME_LABEL_MAP(x._2)))
      .collect().toMap

 def getCookieWithLabel(spark: SparkSession, zookeeper: String, tag: String) = {
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    val data = HdfsOperator.readHdfsFile(sc, COOKIE_LABEL_RESULT_PATH)
    val cookieWithTag = data
      .map(x => x.split(",", 2))
      .map(x => (x(0), JSON.parseFull(x(1)).get.asInstanceOf[collection.immutable.Map[String, List[String]]]))
      .filter(x => x._1.length == 36 && x._2.contains(tag))
      .map(x => (x._1, x._2(tag)(0)))
    //val tmp=cookieWithTag.map(x=>(x._2,x._1)).countByKey()
    //println("getCookieWithLabel")
    //println(tmp.mkString(","))
    cookieWithTag
  }
```

could anyone help me with the question, thx

the data in hdfs just like that
[image]

the log is like that:

```
19/09/11 02:13:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://bi-sp01-west4-b:8020/jc/algorithm/cookie_label_result/part-00049:0+120833
19/09/11 02:13:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://bi-sp01-west4-b:8020/jc/algorithm/cookie_label_result/part-00037:0+114179
19/09/11 02:13:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://bi-sp01-west4-b:8020/jc/algorithm/cookie_label_result/part-00063:0+117746
19/09/11 02:13:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://bi-sp01-west4-b:8020/jc/algorithm/cookie_label_result/part-00030:0+120883
19/09/11 02:13:32 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://bi-sp01-west4-b:8020/jc/algorithm/cookie_label_result/part-00112:0+118313
19/09/11 02:13:32 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 43
19/09/11 02:13:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_43_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 41.5 KB, free 5.2 GB)
19/09/11 02:13:32 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 43 took 8 ms
19/09/11 02:13:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_43 stored as values in memory (estimated size 577.5 KB, free 5.2 GB)
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 30.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 583), reason: Stage cancelled
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 63.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 607), reason: Stage cancelled
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 49.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 599), reason: Stage cancelled
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 37.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 591), reason: Stage cancelled
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 112.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 615), reason: Stage cancelled
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver from bi-sp31-west4-b:34154 disconnected during shutdown
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver from bi-sp31-west4-b:34154 disconnected during shutdown
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /data4/ilambda/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ilambda/appcache/application_1564150399378_26918/spark-522e114a-15ec-4e5d-ac62-0707290cf393
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /data2/ilambda/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ilambda/appcache/application_1564150399378_26918/spark-80ace733-ddc7-43d2-91b6-4838f50fcdf6
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /data1/ilambda/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ilambda/appcache/application_1564150399378_26918/spark-22995903-28f7-4fb6-ab3b-2ef8aad0440d
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /data3/ilambda/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ilambda/appcache/application_1564150399378_26918/spark-f51c43bf-9027-4f68-b770-857b730502b2
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /data6/ilambda/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ilambda/appcache/application_1564150399378_26918/spark-eeca62e4-fd8b-474c-bf36-59733bed1eca
19/09/11 09:42:12 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /data5/ilambda/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ilambda/appcache/application_1564150399378_26918/spark-a3d87914-2a4d-40d3-9da5-3b6527eefb25
```

My spark-submit command like this:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 10G  --driver-memory 10G
```

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: I have provided the form of the data